# pass props in tabs in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I would like to know how to pass a state from my main page to the Tabs? Currently I'm using navigate to transfer props from one page to another page but from Tabs it seems I cannot do that, do you have a function or sample code on how to pass props to the Tabs?

Comment: Hello, without your code it is quite a challenge to help you :) Usually props are passed to nested components like attributes are passed to html tag : <MyReactComponent prop={myValue} />

Comment: What are/is Tabs?

Answer (score 3):

Simply Pass the state as props like this:

```
<SampleComponent 
   sampleProps={this.state.MyMainPageState} 
/>
```

from there you can access it at your SampleComponent as props ;)

inside SampleComponent you can try logging it:

```
//this is the state from your mainPage
const {sampleProps} = this.props; 
 console.log(sampleProps);
```

that should do it