# How refresh tab after adding some data from second Action

Tags: react-native

I have used react native tab view. I have list view in the first tab. I want to add an item to list view from another screen. Refresh data. i try to following code.

```
tabLiability =() =>{
    return <TabLiability ref={(ref) => {
        this.tabLiability = ref;
    }} goToPage={this.goToPage}/>
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("********** recived", nextProps);

    this.tabLiability.test()

}
```

> TypeError: _this.tabLiability is not a function
>   Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

Comment: Does `this.tabLiablility()` have a test() method? I don't think so. Change it to `this.tabLiability()`

Comment: Yes, it has.   test = () => {
        console.log("TabLiability called") // working fine
        this.getClaim(); // network call
    }

Answer (score 0):

Changing data in any tab by any other tab's action.

Thanks to this guy @xSkrappy in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46721776/11392122 I got basic idea from above link and changed according to my need.

As I needed to change the data in a tab by some other tab. So I solved it by this method.

Make a function in your that file where you are actually putting your native base Tabs. I have put that function in states. (in Tab Holder file)

```
this.state= {
msg:"hey",
totalSale: 0,
changefunc : (x) => {
this.setState({
totalSale: x,
}); }
```

My main goal is to get the updated value of this totalSale among some tabs. So i have also put a function name changeFunc in my state so I will call this function in other tabs to setState of totalSale overall the tabs.

To send this to other tabs, I don't know about other tabs procedure, I have just used native base Tabs here. so next step is:

```
<Container>
<Tabs  transparent  >
<Tab heading='Sale'>
   <SaleTab sampleProp= {this.state.changefunc}/>
</Tab>
<Tab >
   <TotalTab navigation={this.props.navigation}  sampleProp= 
    {this.state.totalSale}  />
</Tab>
```

So now in saleTab, whenever I change the value of totalSale, I just call this:

```
 this.props.sampleProp(tsale);  //tsale is any value entered for totalSale
```

and For accessing the changed value in other tab I call this directly on label:

```
 <Label>{this.props.sampleProp} PKR</Label>
```

Make sure your to pass props in your constructor like this:

```
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
 ...// your code stuff
 }
```